# How to get the value from void pointer integer in ctypes if we know the type?

Tags: python, ctypes

Following [Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_void_p)

```
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6") 
>>> strchr = libc.strchr
>>> strchr("abcdef", ord("d")) 
8059983
>>> strchr.restype = c_char_p # c_char_p is a pointer to a string
>>> strchr("abcdef", ord("d"))
'def'
```

Now, suppose I have `8059983` from `strchr("abcdef", ord("d"))` , how can I get `def` without changing `restype`? Is there a dereference function somehow?

Comment: You must set `strchr.restype` to a pointer type, else ctypes returns a `c_int`, which truncates a 64-bit pointer value. So you may as well set it to the correct type. But say it's set to a `c_void_p` instead of `c_char_p`. Simply construct a new instance, e.g. `print c_char_p(8059983).value`.

Comment: @eryksun Is it the same if I set `restype` to `c_int` or `c_void_p`?

Comment: No, `c_int` is a 32-bit integer, but `c_void_p` is a `void *` pointer, which is 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the platform.

Comment: @eryksun Why `c_void_p(8059983).value` returns `8059983`? Should it not return the content in the address `8059983`, like `c_char_p` does?

Comment: The C type is `void`, so there's no value to return other than the address value in the pointer.